# Change background of whole app

Tags: java, android, background

I want to give the users of my app the option to change the background of the whole app . My solution is to create a button and in the onclicklistener, i would change the background of each activity separately with `setBackgroundResource`.

Is there a better way to do this?Or my way is sufficient?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet or have any code?

Comment: Seems sufficient to me.

Comment: I haven't tried it yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this style in res>values>styles.xml

```
<style name="bgThemeDark" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/bg1</item>
</style>
```

and

```
<style name="bgThemeLight" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/bg2</item>
</style>
```

Change `@drawable/bg2` and  `@drawable/bg1` with your background resource.

Then make an `BaseActivity` in your app, extend all activity by `BaseActivity`.

Then write this in `BaseActivity` onCreate

```
boolean darkTheme = true;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setTheme(darkTheme ? R.style.bgThemeDark:R.style.bgThemeLight);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
}
```

**You can also set this in manifest if you don't want change theme at run time.**

```
<application
    android:theme="@style/CustomBackgroundTheme"
```

or

```
<activity
      android:name=".appClasses.activities.ActivityMain"
      android:theme="@style/CustomBackgroundTheme"
      >
```

**Caution:** You should not set any background of any activity layout parent nodes.

Comment: Change `@drawable/ic_launcher` with your background resource.

Comment: What if i want to have 4-5 different backgrounds ?

Comment: Answered in 1 minutes. Amazing answer

Comment: Updated answer to explain you.

Comment: This is way, you need to implement with your need.

Comment: Like you can save styles id in shared preference when user change his preference

Comment: Then you will get style id from shared preference and set theme on onCreate

Comment: @Khemraj Could you explain a bit more each line in the second code(in the base activity) plz

Comment: Okay dude, i will write a sample code for you, once i reach home

Comment: @Khemraj Thanks a lot

Comment: have you achieved your requirement?